# Get difference of 2 arrays but also get which specific side

Tags: javascript, arrays, node.js

Let us say I have 2 arrays:

```
["hello", "world"] vs ["hello", "earth"]
```

ArrayA has a difference of `earth`, where as ArrayB has a difference of `world`.

How would I know this?

Currently I am using underscores difference method.

```
diff = _.difference(ArrayA, ArrayB)
```

But this will only return `world, earth` and I do not know which one of the 2 arrays is missing them.

Or is there a better approach to this?

Comment: What do you expect as the output?

Comment: @thefourtheye I just need to be able to know from which array each difference is coming from so I can append it to the other to make them the same.

Comment: Can you please include your expected output in the question?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
var arr1=["hello", "world"];
var arr2=["hello", "earth"];

var diff = _.difference(ArrayA, ArrayB);

for(var i=0;i<diff.lenght;i++){
    if(arr1.indexOf(diff[i]) != -1){
        //arr2 doesnt have it
    }else{
        //arr1 doesnt have it
    }
}
```